# android studio, c++, windows, filename too long

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

I'm building c++ application for android using Android Studio 2.3.3. Build fails with error:

> Fatal error: can't create
>   CMakeFiles/kore.dir/C_/ab/android-native-build/Sources/src/banan/server/serverData/ServerCompound_banan_server_serverdata_ListValue_IdInt_banan_server_serverdata_ServerCompound_serverdata_ServerAchieve.cpp.o:
>   No such file or directory clang++.exe: error: assembler command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The directory in which this file should be created exists and some other files were successfully created there.

I think this is because of path is too long. I've seen such messages previously and moving project to another directory with shorter path have solved the issue. But now I've already done this.

Comment: Try shortening the filename itself, not the path.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that this will fix the issue. But that's not the way I want to go: C++ project is built from haxe sources and this long filename is result of using generics. I surely can ban this feature but I do not want to do this. I hope there is some command line option or project setting that will help.

Answer (score 0):

shorter your project location because path maximum 256 char long is accepted.